# user.remove_timeout() not working in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

so I was making a mute and unmute command to timeout members and remove the timeout. The timeout command works properly with `user.timeout(time, reason)` but when trying to do `user.remove_timeout(reason)` it gives an error. here is the code and error.

```
@tree.command(name="unmute", description="unmutes a member")
async def unmute(interaction, user: Member):
  if interaction.guild.me.guild_permissions.moderate_members:
    if interaction.user.guild_permissions.moderate_members:
      await user.remove_timeout()
      await interaction.response.send_message(f"{user.mention} has been unmuted successfully!")
```

The error is

```
Cannot access member "remove_timeout" for type "Member"
  Member "remove_timeout" is unknown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.edit()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20member#discord.Member.edit) and set `timed_out_until` to `None` to remove the timeout.
So your code would look like:

```
@tree.command(name="unmute", description="unmutes a member")
async def unmute(interaction, user: Member):
  if interaction.guild.me.guild_permissions.moderate_members:
    if interaction.user.guild_permissions.moderate_members:
      await user.edit(timed_out_until=None)
      await interaction.response.send_message(f"{user.mention} has been unmuted successfully!")
```